# In fish shell, how to set a variable with default fallback?

Tags: environment-variables, fish

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following bash syntax, but for the fish shell:

```
local datafile="${_Z_DATA:-$HOME/.z}"
```

i.e define a local variable that will take the value of `$_Z_DATA` if this one is define, or else will take the value of `$HOME/.z`

Comment: Local variables are not environment variables. An "environment" variable is one exported to be inherited by even subprocesses that aren't `fork()`ed-off copies of the current shell. If you don't use `declare -x`, `set -a`, or `export`, and there wasn't already something marked exported with the same name, a variable is just a regular shell variable, not an environment variable.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no syntax for this; you need something like

```
set datafile "$_Z_DATA"
test -z "$datafile"; and set datafile "$HOME/.z"
```

or

```
if set -q _Z_DATA; and test -n _Z_DATA
  set datafile "$_Z_DATA"
else
  set datafile "$HOME/.z"
end
```

Unlike `bash`, variables defined inside a function are automatically local to that function, so no equivalent to `local` is needed. (A previous version of this answer used the `-l` option to localize the variable, but that makes it local to whatever *block* `set` occurs in.)

Comment: I've already tried the second method with ``if else``, but unfortunately, the variable goes out of scope as soon as exiting the ``if`` block (the second method works fine though)

Comment: drop the `-l` to make the variable function scoped

Comment: `fi`? Don't you mean `end`?

Comment: Yeah, I rarely use `fish` and typed `fi` out of habit.

Answer (score 4):

I would write this as:

```
set -q _Z_DATA; or set _Z_DATA $HOME/.z
```

on fish 3.0+ you can write:

```
set -q _Z_DATA || set _Z_DATA $HOME/.z
```

If you do this a lot you could define a function:

```
function defaultset --no-scope-shadowing
    set -q $argv[1] || set $argv[1] $argv[2..-1]
end

# example usage
defaultset _Z_DATA $HOME/.z
```

Comment: The original `bash` doesn't set the value of `_Z_DATA`; it uses a preexisting value to set `datafile`, or `$HOME/.z` if `_ZDATA` is empty or undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fish expert at all, but I wrote a helper function for this:

```
function default
  for val in $argv
    if test "$val" != ""
      echo $val
      break
    end
  end
end
```

The function echoes the first value that is not empty. (It works with both numbers and strings, too.)

```
~> set baz baz
~> default $foo $bar $baz $bat
baz
~> set bar bar
~> default $foo $bar $baz $bat
bar
```

To use in your script, you can call the function using the parentheses syntax:

```
~> set myfoo (default $foo "default")
~> echo $myfoo
default
~> set foo "the real foo"
~> set myfoo (default $foo "default")
~> echo $myfoo
the real foo
```

Returning to your specific example:

```
set datafile (default "$Z_DATA" "$HOME/.z")
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, keeping n-args simpler than expanding if conditions, other command invocations, or plain additional manual work, and it's even automatic too!  Although I might use `if test -n "$value"` instead.